# Why is there an index error -list out of range - in this PYTHON 3 sketch below? Thanks

Tags: python

```
#this is the  PYTHON 3 sketch:
x =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
i = 0
a = x[i]
while x[i] <=len(x):  #why does this line throw an error
    a == x[i]
    print(a)
    i +=1
print("END")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qherl.png)

This is the error:

```py
while x[i] <=len(x):  #why does this line throw an error
IndexError: list index out of range
```

thoughts: I can get the sketch to run if I place a 9 in the  while statement.
but the length value will not run. Please help with this concern. Thanks

Comment: You get the error because the last item in the list is `10` which, as an integer, is less than or equal to the length of the list `x`. This allows the loop to go round one more time, including executing: `x += 1`, which then overflows `x` causing the index out of range.

Comment: You should print the value of `i` when you get that error.  You will find that `i` is not in the range `0..9`, which are the indexes into a 10 element array, which is what you defined.

Comment: I may understand this incorrectly, but the while statement value is compared to the length of the list. The list has 10 elements, so it should loop up to that length and print the indexed values. I think.

Comment: Yes, it does print those things, but also the loop has to carry on and execute: `i += 1` which sets the index to one more than the last index, so when the code tries to execute: `x[i] <=len(x)`, the `x[i]` causes an exception.

Comment: Ok, If you  will please, how should I structure the  while statement to re print the list. The increment statement seems to not increase beyond the first value of the list also. Thanks

Comment: What did you think of the answer from shoaib30? The best way is really a `for` loop.

Comment: Hello I used this while statement;while i < 10: and the sketch worked. but I wanted to make this scalable fo receive any amount of values in the ist and placing 9 in the while statement negates this. I want to thank eveyone that took time to respond.. Enjoy your days.

Comment: The truly scalable version is: `for a in x: print(a)`

Answer (score 2):

The index values in a list start from 0 and go up to one less than the length of the list

removing the `=` sign should fix the code

```
#this is the  PYTHON 3 sketch:
x =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
i = 0
a = x[i]
while x[i] <len(x):  #why does this line throw an error
    a = x[i]
    print(a)
    i +=1
print("END")
```

Generally, you won't have a list like the one you have now. In those cases, it'll be better to write either `while i < len(x):` or `for i in range(len(x))`. If you're using the for-loop with range way, then you should leave the `i += 1` line.

**Edit:**
Assuming you are trying to iterate over a List `x` and print it. Below are some methods to achieve it.

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Using While Loop
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    a = x[i]
    print(a)
    i += 1

# Using For Loop
for a in x:
    print(a)
```

There are many more ways to achieve it, you can find it here:
https://www.askpython.com/python/list/iterate-through-list-in-python

Comment: I truly appreciate your time and effort in responding to my problem. I tried your while & for suggestion and I received a vertical output of one's and End. I thought , probably wrong, that len() in the line : while x[i] <= len(x) would loop until the lenth of the list was extinguished not before or afterwards. The counter is not working in the for loop attempt it outputs only 1's and END the while loop attempt says while i < len(x): same as for loop. Really a puzzle for me. Thanks again just a newby tryin 2 learn.

Comment: I also tried removing the = from my <=  while statement and it returned 1's removed 1 from the list to check for loop count and got 2's. Can't understand why loop is not counting either. sorry for my naivete. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user14937123 you also had `a ==x[i]` which is for comparison and not for assignment. Hence the value of `a` never changed